# Filter of two lists for the same elements via LINQ query in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have an event that I listen to. This event is triggered when something changes in the setting of a device. This event then gives me a list of all available devices.

Now I have so-called **station**, each of which is linked to a **device**.
I send a query which returns all these stations.

[image]

Both fields own a `DeviceUid` property.
Now I want to execute a certain function for each device, which was also found in the station (see code snippet):

Event:

```
public class DeviceEvent
{
    public virtual List<DeviceInfo> Device { get; set; }
}
```

My Method:

```
public void SomeMethod(DeviceEvent evt)
{
    var stations = Do.Query(new GetStationQuery(){ SomeInput })
                     .Where(x => x.DeviceIsRegistered)
                     .ToList();
    
    // type: List<DeviceInfo>            
    var deviceInfoList = evt.Device;
    
    // TODO: get DeviceInfo for each Device which can be found in stations.
    
    foreach (var VARIABLE in COLLECTION)
    {
        DoSomething(station, deviceInfo);
    }
}   


private void DoSomething(StationInfo stationInfo,
                         DeviceInfo deviceInfo)
{
    // some code
}
```

**My approach:**

Store the corresponding `DeviceUid` from the `stations` as a separate list (`var stationDeviceUidList`).
I then check if an element (`Uid`) from the `deviceInfoList` can be found in the `stationDeviceUidList`.

Then I get all `DeviceInfo` with the found `Uids` and give them to the `DoSomething()` method as parameter.

```
var stationDeviceUidList = stations.Select(x => x.DeviceId);
var deviceUidList = deviceInfoList.Select(x => x.DeviceUid)
                                  .ToList();
                                  
// How do I get a corresponding Uid here?
var test = deviceUidList.Where(x => deviceUidList.Contains(stationDeviceUidList));
```

I can't get the last step right and the query for the matching of the ids is definitely wrong.

Does my approach even make sense? What is the reason for my error?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Do you mean to adapt the query like the following e.g. .Where(x => x.DeviceIsRegistered).Where(x => x.DeviceUid == deviceInfoList.Find(y => y.DeviceUid)).ToList();
only this linq statement is most likely wrong :/

Comment: So when something changes on any device you get a list of ALL devices, even those who have experienced no change?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes exactly (sadly)

Comment: Tim means like `allStations.Where(s => eventDeviceList.Any(d => d.DeviceId == s.Device.Id))` - this is "for all stations, give only the stations where (event device list has any item where the device is equal to the stations's device's id)" - ie "give only those stations with devices whose Id is in the list of event device's IDs"

Comment: In terms of logic it's perhaps "upside down" compared to how most people jump to thinking of it- "get me stations where the device id is in this list" is easy to grasp - it's like "go shopping and get me items that are a member of this shopping list", but the Any() form is more like "get me stations where any member of this list of device ids is equal to the station device ID" and is harder to see, but they amount to the same thing. ps; not having the definition of station class makes it harder but you seem to say that station has a deviceid, so `s.Device.Id` could be `s.DeviceId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality should solve the problem. Thanks to the approach of the two answers I was able to adapt the corresponding LINQ commands.

In the upper query it is enough to query the station **for the registered device**, because each station contains only one device.

And in the `foreach` loop, I can also use `Single()` and pass this information to the new method.

```
public void SomeMethod(DeviceEvent evt)
{
    var stationsInfo = var stations = Do.Query(new GetStationQuery(){ SomeInput });

    var stationsForDevice = stationsInfo.Where(info => info.DeviceIsRegistered);

    foreach (var stationInfo in stationsForDevice)
    {
        var deviceInfo = evt.Device.Single(info => info.DeviceUid.Equals(stationInfo.DeviceId));
        DoSomething(stationInfo, deviceInfo );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your station class looks like

```
class Station{

  DeviceInfo Device = ...
  int DeviceId = ... //or guid, doesn't matter

}
```

And your DeviceInfo looks like:

```
class DeviceInfo{

  int DeviceUid = ... //or guid, doesn't matter, this is equal to station.DeviceId

}
```

And your event list of DeviceInfo is called Devices (lists of classes should be plural)

You can:

```
context.Stations.Where(s => Devices.Any(d => d.DeviceUid == s.DeviceId))
```

This means is "for all stations, give only the stations where (event device list has any item where the device is equal to the stations's device's id)" - ie "give only those stations with devices whose Id is in the list of event device's IDs"

You seem to have some method that produces a station list, which I can't see inside but I wouldn't recommend ToList()ing your stations first (at any stage) as it will mean your client downloads every station. If you leave it as a queryable then the query can be formed without needing to download every station so only the stations you want will download

Oh, and you can stack other conditions into your where:

```
context.Stations.Where(s => s.IsRegistered && Devices.Any(d => d.DeviceUid == s.DeviceId))
```